# RXJS - 3 parallel observables, then emit value and use this to call 3 observables in series

Tags: angular, rxjs

**CLOSED**

Maybe my question is a bit complicated but I can't figure out how to realize what I want.

**Context**
Three parallels observables emits value, then, when I've all three values, I modify them a little and then I want to call three observable in series.
Like the image below: 
[image]

**Now?**
For the moment I managed to do this by putting my three parallel observable in a **zip** operator then subscribe to it, modify the value, and on complete, call the other one, subscribe, and on complete.. Three times !

```js
this.service.Function(id) //return zip(Ob1, Ob2, Ob3)
  .subscribe(
    ([val1, val2, val3]) => {
      /*DO SOMETHING*/
      this.tmp1 = val1;
      this.tmp2 = val2;
      this.tmp3 = val3;
    },
    () => {}, //on error
    () => { //on complete
      let newV1, newV2, newV3 = [];
      [newV1, newV2, newV3 ] = [
        this.tmp1.map(x => x.id2),
        this.tmp2.map(x => x.id2),
        this.tmp3.map(x => x.id2)
      ];
      this.service.Function2(newV1)
        .subscribe(res => {
            //DO SOMETHING
          },
          () => {},
          () => { //on complete
            this.service.Function2(newV2)
              .subscribe(res => {
                  //DO SOMETHING
                },
                () => {},
                () => { //on complete
                  this.service.Function2(newV3)
                    .subscribe(res => {
                        //DO SOMETHING
                      },
                      () => {},
                      () => {
                        //DO SOMETHING
                      });
                });
          });
    }
  );
```

**What I tried**
I tried something different with **switchMap** and **concat** but concat doesn't return me my values as Array...

```js
this.kycService.getDocuments(idNotif).pipe(
  switchMap(([val1, val2, val3]) => {
    this.tmp1 = val1;
    this.tmp2 = val2;
    this.tmp3 = val3;

    let newV1, newV2, newV3 = [];
      [newV1, newV2, newV3 ] = [
        this.tmp1.map(x => x.id2),
        this.tmp2.map(x => x.id2),
        this.tmp3.map(x => x.id2)
      ];
    return concat(this.service.Function2(newV1),this.service.Function2(newV2), this.service.Function2(newV3))
  }))
  .subscribe(([Ob_newV1, Ob_newV2, Ob_newV3]) => {
    //DO SOMETHING
    //[Ob_newV1, Ob_newV2, Ob_newV3] Doesn't work, I need to do val => {}
  })
);
```

If you have any advice on what to use, I'm a bit confused by all the operators/functions in RXJS..

Thank you in advance

**My solution**

```js
    this.kycService.getDocuments(idNotif).pipe(
  switchMap(([val1, val2, val3]) => {
    this.tmp1 = val1;
    this.tmp2 = val2;
    this.tmp3 = val3;

    let newV1, newV2, newV3 = [];
      [newV1, newV2, newV3 ] = [
        this.tmp1.map(x => x.id2),
        this.tmp2.map(x => x.id2),
        this.tmp3.map(x => x.id2)
      ];
    return concat(this.service.Function2(newV1),this.service.Function2(newV2), this.service.Function2(newV3))
  }))
  .subscribe((val) => {
    //DO SOMETHING
    //val is emitted every time my function2 complete, so I manage to deal with this and rearrange my data
  })
);
```

Comment: `.pipe(toArray())`?

Comment: It seems like you're looking for `forkJoin` but I'm not really sure what these `this.service.Function2(...)` functions do

Comment: @JBNizet it works but.. When I do this with ``.subscribe((val) => {`` it emit the value only when all 3 (or 4 in the image) observable complete.. Without this, it emit the value every time my observable emit something..
I'll go without toArray and work on the response ! Thanks !

Answer (score 6):

Depends on your Observable types.

For hot observables (subjects, stores, etc), you will use `combineLatest`.

For cold observables (of, HTTP calls, from promises, etc.), you will use `forkJoin`.

Let's assume they're cold.

```js
forkJoin(
  first$.pipe(
    map(result => /* transformation of your first observable */),
    switchMap(result => this.myService.getNextObservableFromFirst())
  ),
  second$.pipe(
    map(result => /* transformation of your second observable */),
    switchMap(result => this.myService.getNextObservableFromSecond())
  ),
  third$.pipe(
    map(result => /* transformation of your third observable */),
    switchMap(result => this.myService.getNextObservableFromThird())
  ),

).subscribe([r1, r2, r3] => /* What to do once all calls are completed */);
```

It seems that adapted to your case, it would give

```js
forkJoin(
  first$.pipe(
    map(result => result.id2),
    switchMap(result => this.myService.Function2(result))
  ),
  second$.pipe(
    map(result => result.id2),
    switchMap(result => this.myService.Function2(result))
  ),
  third$.pipe(
    map(result => result.id2),
    switchMap(result => this.myService.Function2(result))
  ),

).subscribe([r1, r2, r3] => /* DO SOMETHING */);
```

Comment: OP says that asynchronous calls are made serially once the zip returns array of observables. But `forkJoin` does not handle this situation i guess. `forkJoin` is suitable when parallel requests are made.

Comment: All of his calls are already made, forkjoin is just there to make a callback once all the requests have been completed.

Comment: And by the way @AmitChigadani, I'm getting rid of the `zip` here too

Comment: Ok, but still the pattern `first sequence as parallel and the second sequence as serial` is lost here. This would not behave in the same way as shown in the image.

Comment: I don't see images (corporate proxy), So I rely on the provided code. And given the code he has provided, the statement you've just quoted is wrong : it's not 3 calls in parallel then 3 calls in serial, it's one call, then another call from the transformed result, times 3. But OP will try and tell me if it's not what he expected, in this case I will update my answer.

Comment: @trichetriche Merci ! Based on your answer, and the fact that you can't see my image (satané proxy..), my question is not clear.. My image provide exactly what I needed.. For the moment; I managed to achieve what I want by using my second method with some work on the returning data !